# Phonegap app and remote server data exchange

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am creating a phonegap and jquerymobile app, what i want to know is if ii is possible to post form input data to external server and also retrieve database data from an external server without having problem with same domain policy or cross-domain policy.

EDIT --
Thank you guys for your swift responds, i also want to know if it is first of GOOD IDEA and secondly SAFE to pass html formatted data from an external server to a jquerymobile phonegap app

example, i make a request from phonegap app to a server and it return data formatted like the one below.

```
<li><a href="#itemDetail">
  <img src="../icons/up-16.png" class="ui-li-icon"/>
  <h3>dsdfgsd</h3>
  <p>Location: 1sdgsdgsdg,  Ashanti Region</p>
  <span class="ui-li-count">23.6 Miles</span>
  </a></li>
    <li><a href="#itemDetail">
  <img src="../icons/up-16.png" class="ui-li-icon"/>
  <h3>David Addoteye</h3>
  <p>Location: Accra,  Central Region</p>
  <span class="ui-li-count">23.6 Miles</span>
  </a></li>
    <li><a href="#itemDetail">
  <img src="../icons/up-16.png" class="ui-li-icon"/>
  <h3>Florence Asamoah</h3>
  <p>Location: Accra,  Eastern Region</p>
  <span class="ui-li-count">23.6 Miles</span>
  </a></li>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible using the [Domain Whitelisting](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide) capability in PhoneGap. This lets you work within the acceptable limits of same-origin policy in a supported manner.

You would also need something like jQuery to make the communication with the external server - using either JSONP or CORS. You could read more about that [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

UPDATE: And using CORS etc. with PhoneGap is easier with jQuery mobile - Check out this [link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html) shared by [MelanciaUK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2191976/melanciauk) in the comment.

Comment: Thanks @MelanciaUK. Updated the answer to include the PhoneGap support from jQuery mobile

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be possible. Check [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html).

Comment: Please explain your answer here and when needed with a link. But not just a link. Cheers